# How to update an existing web map if I need to add a new feature layer to the ArcGIS Pro map the web map is sourced from?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, update, arcgis-online-webmap

I have created a web map through the following process:

*Create map in ArcGIS Pro-->Publish it as Web Layer-->Open hosted feature layer and save as web map.*

I know that I can push through updates to the existing layers in the Web Map by editing them in the ArcGIS Pro map and then using "Overwrite Web Layer".  This works.

However, I need to add a new layer to the map in ArcGIS Pro and also need that layer to show up in the Web Map. The Overwrite does not seem to work for this - the new layer does not show up in the Web Map.

I know that I could publish the ArcGIS Pro map with the new layer added as a completely new Web Layer and then build a new Web Map.  BUT, the existing Web Map has a lot of popups configured that took a lot of time to make, so I'd have to recreate all those popups if I have to publish it as a new Web Layer.

Is there a way to push the new layer through to the existing Web Map - via Overwrite or another way?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Here's what I did to try that:  In AGOL, I opened the existing Web Map.  I selected Add Layers and browsed to the layer that had been overwritten and added it to the map.  The new layer that had been added in ArcPro DOES show up.  However, none of the popup formatting that had been done in the Web Map is transferred.  I'm looking for a solution that both: a) allows the newly added layer from ArcPro to show up in the Web Map AND b) retain the popup formatting that had been done previously for other layers in the Web Map.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  That does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do in similar situations (although not exactly the same situation, so YMMV):

Add the updated hosted feature layer (group of layers) to the map (again) WITHOUT deleting the existing equivalent group of layers from the map.  So you will now have two versions of that group of layers in the map:

- The old layer group, with the correctly configured pop-ups, but missing the new layer(s)
- The new layer group, with the unconfigured pop-ups, but including the new layer(s)

(Ie, most of your layers will be on the map twice at this point - in both the old and new layer group.)

Now drag the new layer(s) from the newly added layer group, into the old layer group.  Then delete the newly added layer group.